# How to gracefully scale a div / background image to reveal more depending on the window size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a page that can scale down to support small browsers, but take advantage of the majority of browser sizes that most visitors are using.

I have a background image that is bigger than 1024x728, but the most important parts of the image are contained within 1024x728... It's like a magazine's bleed - there's extra image there if its needed (and it looks better if fully expanded) but it's not necessary.

I have included an example to illustrate what I mean:

http://tinypic.com/r/24l5she/7

The "background image" is the entire red box in the larger browser window, and there's a repeating texture it sits within (the blue). The "white box with red arrows" is the "minimum size" I want to accept. What I am trying to do, depending on the size of the user's browser, is cut out parts of the image until the browser reaches some specific minimum size.

Can this be done within a framework like 960.gs?

Really looking forward to your responses!

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Put your page in a fixed-width wrapper div, then add a centered background-image to the body tag.

Comment: Can I use a centred background-image and a repeating texture?

Answer (score 1):

With CSS3's `background-size` property, you can force the image to stay a constant size. Then it's just a matter of a `no-repeat center center` bit in your `background` declaration.

```
div {
    background: url('yourpic.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 1024px 768px
}
```

You didn't really want to support IE<=8, did you?

Comment: Thanks Marc. 3.5% of my visitors use IE 8 and 1.1% use 7... so 4% is somewhat significant.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but more of a food for thought...

Seeing as your background image is so large, you may want to just remove it from mobile devices. While most of them can handle it, it's just extra data that needs to be transferred and most mobile carriers have strict data limits.

Like I said, just something to consider. :)